# Magento1.9: New product Image upload from magento to pinterest

Tags: magento-1.9, api, soap-api-v1

Is it possible to post a Magento product image to pinterest.

When I create product it's image is automatically uploaded from Magento to Pinterest.

Actually in my website there are 1000+ product images and i want to upload they all so is there any way to do that.

Answer (score 2):

It requires a bit of coding to upload Magento images to Pinterest. 
As I found one thing on the stack that there are 3 way to upload an image with API on Pinterest. you can read more here https://stackoverflow.com/a/33027906/7472487

In that, there is one option that if an image is already on the web(internet) then with API you just need to pass image URL so it will take your image from that URL and stores on the Pinterest. (you need to follow Pinterest API which you can find here https://developers.pinterest.com/docs/api/pins/

Now a thing is to do this stuff with Magento. There are two ways for that.

1) If a product is already added in Magento then you need to write one script where you need to load all products and fetch image URL of that product and call Pinterest API to pass that images.

2) way if you want to add product image when you add a product in Magento then you need to create one module in which you need to create one observer for product_save_after in that you need to get image URL of product and pass them in the Pinterest API so an image will be uploaded.

I have described here how this thing can be achieved. you can write code for API based on Pinterest developer documentation.

You can get PHP Demo for Pinterest API from here https://github.com/dirkgroenen/Pinterest-API-PHP

Hope it helps.

To Add Pinterest Lib go to your Magento root directory and run below command

```
composer require dirkgroenen/Pinterest-API-PHP
composer update
```

after that your Pinterest lib will work without any error.

Comment: I have already load all products and fetch image URL but i dont know how to call pinterest API to Pass images. do you have API Code for that.  We have tried this one :-https://api.pinterest.com/v1/pins/?board=511651276354999380&note=Demo_text&image_url=https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/SrULGsyndXJk6Gs4Lmv34sOlMDAroy1bzPPr9X1U5oVdv5TAAJX4JkYPO_wQAdP7TBA=w300&access_token=AfRW8VxUR77NhQ8FaETwJb7X8wkcFQKSWTnO-ahEkLvUiqBCRAAAAAA    but its not working

Comment: I have updated my answer I have added Pinterest PHP lib over there you will get sample source code to upload image with PHP

Comment: we have tried that code and got this error:-Warning: require(../vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream

Comment: I already tried this before but face this error at that time

Comment: above error you are getting because it is not able to find Pinterest lib in your system.

Comment: I have updated answer.

Comment: From where i can get pinterest library

Comment: ok i am trying now and let you know

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71166/discussion-between-jaimin-and-magento2-learner).

Comment: is that worked ?

Comment: Can you come into chat room